# How to get JsonCPP values as strings?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I am parsing json data using [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp). I don't really need to understand the data, i just need to print out some properties and their values out. It somehow is hard to do. First I need to know what type the value is and then get the value and then convert it to string again! There is a styled writer but I don't want to use it as it appends some CRLF at the end.

I do something like this

```
CJsonHelper::getUInt(Json::Value &root, std::string key){
    return root.get(key, 0-1).isInt() ? root.get(key, 0-1).asUInt() : 0-1;
}
```

Could I just write a single function to get all the properties with just that function which doesn't really care about the types etc?

Comment: Why are you using `0-1` instead of just `-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trivially create your own writer that does whatever you want. Have look at the code for `StyledWriter`. The CRLF's you don't like come from `StyledWriter::Write`. You can create your own writer class that doesn't have those CRLF's.

If you don't mind modifying the library, change the writer so that functions like `writeValue` are protected rather than private. Then you can derive your own class from `StyledWriter` with a different `Write` function and still use the various `write*` functions to do the details of the conversion.

Answer (score 12):

The project has moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/).

To avoid all linefeeds, use a [StreamWriterBuilder](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_stream_writer_builder.html):

```
Json::Value whatever = ...;
Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder;
builder.settings_["indentation"] = "";
std::string out = Json::writeString(builder, whatever);
```