# Converting a Json::Value to std::string?

Tags: c++, stdstring, jsoncpp

I am using [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) to build a JSON object. Once the object is built, is there a way I can get the object as an `std::string`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use a [Json::Writer](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_writer.html) to do exactly this, since I assume you want to save it somewhere so you don't want human readable output, your best bet would be to use a [Json::FastWriter](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_fast_writer.html) and then you can call the `write` method with the parameter of your [Json::Value](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html) (ie. your root) and then that simply returns a `std::string` like so:

```
Json::FastWriter fastWriter;
std::string output = fastWriter.write(root);
```

Comment: Although this works great, the current version of JsonCPP says Json::FastWriter has been deprecated in favor of Json::StreamWriterBuilder. But the functionality of writing to a string was removed, and now it is necessary to write to a std::stringstream. Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 32):

[`Json::Writer` is deprecated.](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/deprecated.html) Use [`Json::StreamWriter`](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_stream_writer.html) or [`Json::StreamWriterBuilder`](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_stream_writer_builder.html) instead.

[`Json::writeString`](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/namespace_json.html#a4cd945e3d7722c3fabc38e14efacb6f8) writes into a stringstream and then returns a string:

```
Json::Value json = ...;
Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder;
builder["indentation"] = ""; // If you want whitespace-less output
const std::string output = Json::writeString(builder, json);
```

Kudos to cdunn2001's answer here: [How to get JsonCPP values as strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844856/how-to-get-jsoncpp-values-as-strings)

Answer (score 18):

You can also use the method toStyledString().

```
jsonValue.toStyledString();
```

The method "**toStyledString()**" converts any value to a formatted string.
See also the link: [doc for toStyledString](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JsonCpp#toStyledString())

Answer (score 4):

If your `Json::value` is of string type, e.g. "bar" in the following json

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

You can use `Json::Value.asString` to get the value of `bar` without extra quotes(which will be added if you use `StringWriterBuilder`). Here is an example:

```
Json::Value rootJsonValue;
rootJsonValue["foo"] = "bar";
std::string s = rootJsonValue["foo"].asString();
std::cout << s << std::endl; // bar
```

Answer (score 1):

In my context, I instead used a simple *.asString()* at the end of my json value object. As @Searene said, it gets rid of the extra quotes that you don't necessary wants if you want to process it after.

```
Json::Value credentials;
Json::Reader reader;

// Catch the error if wanted for the reader if wanted. 
reader.parse(request.body(), credentials);

std::string usager, password;
usager = credentials["usager"].asString();
password = credentials["password"].asString();
```

If the value is a int instead of a string, *.asInt()* works great as well.

Answer (score 0):

This little helper might do.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// json.asString()
//
std::string JsonAsString(const Json::Value &json)
{
    std::string result;
    Json::StreamWriterBuilder wbuilder;

    wbuilder["indentation"] = "";       // Optional
    result = Json::writeString(wbuilder, json);
    return result;
}
```