# JSONCPP is adding extra double quotes to string

Tags: c++, string, jsoncpp

I have a root in JSONcpp having string value like this.

```
Json::Value root;
std::string val =  "{\"stringval\": \"mystring\"}";
Json::Reader reader;
bool parsingpassed = reader.parse(val, root, false);
```

Now when I am trying to retrieve this value using this piece of code.

```
Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder;
builder.settings_["indentation"] = "";
std::string out = Json::writeString(builder, root["stringval"]);
```

here out string ideally should be giving containing:

```
"mystring"
```

whereas it is giving output like this:

```
"\"mystring\"" \\you see this in debug mode if you check your string content
```

by the way if you print this value using `stdout` it will be printed something like this::

```
"mystring" \\ because \" is an escape sequence and prints " in stdout
```

it should be printing like this in `stdout`:

```
mystring \\Expected output
```

Any idea how to avoid this kind of output when converting json output to std::string ? 
Please avoid suggesting fastwriter as it also adds newline character and it deprecated API as well.

Constraint: I do not want to modify the string by removing extra \" with string manipulation rather I am willing to know how I can I do that with JSONcpp directly.

[This is StreamWriterBuilder Reference code which I have used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844856/how-to-get-jsoncpp-values-as-strings)

[Also found this solution, which gives optimal solution to remove extra quotes from your current string , but I don't want it to be there in first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724448/simple-json-string-escape-for-c/33799784#33799784)

Comment: I can't reproduce this output.

Comment: I am using JsonCPP 1.7.4

Comment: Tested with current 1.8.0 and just tested with 1.7.4. Still can't.

Comment: Can't confirm either. I suggest you attach the debugger and step through the code to see where those quotes are added.

Comment: Okay yes I got the problem , wait Updating question.

Comment: Updated information , Please stay in debugging mode and check the content of string...

Comment: Say it contained `"1"`. If it printed as just `1`, how would you know it wasn't an integer?

Comment: If you write Hello World program also check what it prints "Hello World" or Hello World ?? ... Don't mean to offend you, just giving the example

Comment: How do you print your content? Are you using Qt Creator and qDebug()? If so, it's just the way it's displayed.

Comment: No Actually I am not printing it .. I am simply running it in Xcode in debug mode. So I can see there are extra double qoutes available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so This question did not get answer after thorough explanation as well and I had to go through JSONCPP apis and documentation for a while.

I did not find any api as of now which takes care of this scenario of extra  double quote addition.
Now from their wikibook I could figure out that some escape sequences might come in String. It is as designed and they haven't mentioned exact scenario.

```
   \" - quote
   \\ - backslash
   \/ - slash
   \n - newline
   \t - tabulation
   \r - carriage return
   \b - backspace
   \f - form feed
   \uxxxx , where x is a hexadecimal digit - any 2-byte symbol
```

[Link Explaining what all extra Escape Sequence might come in String](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JsonCpp)

Anyone coming around this if finds out better explanation for the same issue , please feel free to post your answer.Till then I guess only string manipulation is the option to remove those extra escape sequence..

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem also until I realized you have to use the `Json::Value` class accessor functions, e.g. `root["stringval"]` will be `"mystring"`, but `root["stringval"].asString()` will be `mystring`.

Comment: asString() solved my problem, since I was using toStyledString().